# Can anyone tell me how to get the background animation effect used in Oculus Connect 3 website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, canvas

[Oculus Connect 3](https://www.oculusconnect.com/)

I know this site was built on react. I want to know more about how to get that background animation and mouse over effect. It's simply awesome to experience. Based on this I will decide to go with React or Angular 2.

Comment: That looks like it's one of those "Just because we can" backgrounds

Comment: It's not specific to React. It's a custom canvas function. Take a look at [particles.js](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/), it's quite similar.

Comment: Thank you @FabianSchultz for referring particles.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open your browser's inspection tool (almost always F12) you can see the layout of the webpage. It contains a canvas element with the id "grid". The animation is made using this.

The animation itself looks like a simple node graph, where if you move your cursor the nodes close to the cursor try to stay away from it, thus creating an explosion-like effect.

If your cursor stays fix for 2-3 seconds, the animation starts using a point going randomly across the page instead.

I doubt this animation uses too much of any of the libraries you mentioned in your question, thus deciding which one of these you will be using based on this demo (which let's be honest, max 200 lines of vanilla JavaScript) is like deciding what you eat for breakfast based on the food statistics of Mongolia.

And also, animations like this are what scares off most users. I don't think you can show me any big multimedia or social network site, which has animation close to this.

Comment: thanks for the info. I didn't properly inspected the DOM using developer tools. I just checked only virtual DOM and didn't searched for canvas element. I believe these type animation effects looks great on landing web pages.

Comment: @Kumar on a pretty strong computer I get a very very bad framerate on this page, wich isn't acceptable